# User Summary Jumps on Mouse Over

Tags: bug, status-norepro

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33270346/to-cms-or-not-to-cms) has several tags with longish text.

When I mouse over a tag, the text *edit tags* appears after the last text.  The user summary under the tags also jumps to the right a bit.  This does not happen for questions with shorter tags.

Observed in Version 46.0.2490.71 m of Chrome on Windows.

Here's a screenshot without and with the mouse over (alignment lines added)

[image]

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Chrome v46 on Fedora 22 Linux.

Comment: Also, the example post has been downvoted, closed and deleted.